# How do I reference a component in an inline web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-2.0, custom-component

I have a free hosting service that is stuck in ASP.NET 2.0.  Additionally, it constrains users to only inline versions (no codebehind).  However, it does allow references to custom components.  I have built an inline .asmx and would, ideally, like to 'include'/'use' a component I've built.  How do I do this inline?  I've tried 'using [Namespace]', but get a compilation error.  I've also tried using, in the WebMethod [Namespace of Component].[Method] as well.  Again, this produces a compilation error.  I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this else where.  The component is not compiled into a DLL and will work if referenced in a web form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Import` directive to import a namespace:

```
<%@ Import namespace="My.Namespace" %>
```

**EDIT**: Sorry for the misinformation. You'll want to use the `Assembly` directive for an ASMX web service:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="MyAssembly" %>
```

or

```
<%@ Assembly Src="path/myFile.cs" %>
```

Since the code you are referencing is not compiled, you'll want to use the latter version of the directive to point to the source file. The `Src` attribute points to a source file to dynamically compile and link against.

Comment: What does `Assembly` do with the `Src` attribute?

Comment: @John Saunders - Per MSDN:The `Src` attribute indicates "the path to a source file to dynamically compile and link against."