# How to reference a custom DLL from an uncompiled .NET webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, dll

For various reasons I'll not go into I need to write my .NET webservice outside of Visual Studio. This in itself is not difficult and the following works fine...

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="TestHW" %>

using System;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml.Serialization

[WebService(Namespace="http://www.mydomain.com/services")]
public class TestHW : WebService {
    [WebMethod()]
    public string Add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

I need to reference a custom .NET DLL from this webservice, but I can't get the .asmx to find the DLL (which resides in the same directory). Google is difficult because everyone apparently wants to reference a webservice from a DLL not the other way around. Everything is targeting .NET 2.0.

```
using websvc; //DLL is websvc.dll with namespace websvc
```

gives the error...

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'websvc' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

finally found at [How do I reference a component in an inline web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345875/how-do-i-reference-a-component-in-an-inline-web-service)

```
<%@ Assembly Name="MyAssembly" %>
```

or

```
<%@ Assembly Src="path/myFile.cs" %>
```

The name syntax is for compiled DLLs and the src syntax is for open code. The dll seems to need to be in a bin directory under the root.